# Getting started with Qualcomm reference designs

Tags: pcb-design, design, arm, mobile, pcb-antenna

I am looking to get started with Qualcomm Reference Designs.

I am partly inspired by this article: ["Start Your Own Smartphone Company for $1,000"](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2015-07-13/how-1-000-buys-a-smartphone-brand-to-challenge-samsung).

I have an application that I would like to be able to run on my own hardware for various reasons and to save development time I would like to start with reference designs and fit the hardware into the appropriate casing for our application.

I have been through [Qualcom reference designs website](https://qrd.qualcomm.com) and it is circular and lacks information even with a login.

In addition to this website developer. qualcomm that has two platforms worth working with but a comprehensive spec only available for the 410c

I contacted all the design houses qualcomm had listed online but they seem to only deal with bigger customers. I am finding it somewhat slow to deal with Zuoer in China as mentioned in the bloomberg article.

To get started with reference designs I need a list of what is available and spec sheets for those designs so I can line them up against our test devices and find the right one for our application.

Any information is appreciated, thank you to everyone.

Comment: "Qualcomm" -> NDAs, buckets of 'em.

Answer (score 6):

As someone who has been in the electronics sales and distribution world for a couple years now, I can say from experience that the majority of mobile handset chipset suppliers such as Qualcomm have their documentation on a secure portal and will only grant access to either top tier customers or other tier 1 customers that sign NDAs where the suppliers feel that the customer is a strategic partner.  Otherwise, you're left dealing with a SoM vendor such as Intrinsyc.